# nightwatch - check for popup window, after each click event

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, nightwatch.js

Is there a way in nightwatch to check whether a popup window appears after each click event?

I have a problem that randomly an error message appear and I don't want to write for each click event the same callback function.

I have already tried out the `after` and `afterEach` commands in the Global.js but then the commands will only run after the whole test suite.

I also have tried it local within a test file, although it also does not cover all single click events, even though the official website writes "... while `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are ran before and after each testcase (test step)"?

Solution I'm looking for:

```
.waitForElementVisible('selector')
    .click('selector')  
    .click('selector')
```

Solution I have come up with so far:

```
.waitForElementVisible('selector')
    .click('selector', isPresent)  
    .click('selector', isPresent)
```

`isPresent` as a callback function, which does the checking and close the popup window if it appears.

Is there another way to write a function (with or without `after` and/or `forEach`), so that it will be called after each click event or after each command. Thus, I don't have to write the `isPresent` repetitive code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert something like this in your page object file:

```
var popupCommand = {
 popupCheck:function(){
return this.waitForElementVisible('selector', 5000)
  .click('selector', isPresent)
  .click('selector', isPresent)

},

module.exports = {
commands:[popupCommand],
elements:{
firstElement: {selector: 'xpath',locateStrategy: 'xpath'},
secondElement: {selector: 'css'},


 }
}
```

Where 'popupCommand' will be the name of your page object file, for example 'Popup'. And also you will have to insert your isPresent callback function here so you can use it. 
I did my best to explain you as much as possible what and how to do that :)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

you should yse .switchWindow() method.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but my problem still remains. I still have to check whether the error window has pops up or not. Therefore, I have to copy the callback function for the .click() event each time. I'm trying to avoid it by specifying it once globally and it will be called automatically after each event. Just like foreEach although, unfortunately it does not work globally neither locally. Thkans!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own custom command specific for that case, so that way you will avoid repetitive code?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out a way in doing it. Nevertheless, I would still have to call the custom command after the click() event each time?

Comment: But with the custom command you can do that with the only one command, thats the difference